# Adding C# form into another form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, panel

I need to add the form into the panel of the another parent form, but that is not working. When I try to add within the main parent form. I have a dashboard form and when I click the button a sidebar for gets open into one of the panels and again I need to load the form into the second panel of the dashboard form when I click on the button of the sidebar form.

```cs
public void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Admin_Dashboard frm = new Admin_Dashboard();

    Brand.Add_Brand myform = new Brand.Add_Brand();

    myform.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    myform.TopLevel = false;
    myform.AutoScroll = true;
    frm.content.Controls.Clear();
    frm.content.Controls.Add(myform);

    myform.Show();
}
```

Comment: Forms cannot be added into a panel. A Form is such a thing with Title-Bar and Min/Max-Buttons. Maybe you talk about Controls.

Comment: @Holger A `Form` is a `Control`, and can certainly be added to a `Panel`.

Comment: @rfmodulator As a component, yes. Should I put it in softer words ? It makes no sense, you don't do it, and I have never seen anybody doing it. Maybe it's technically possible. Drag an OpenFileDialog to a Panel, see what happens. Owner and Parent are two different things. A Form has an Owner, a Child Control has a parent. One youd display with Controls.Add, the other one with Form.Show().

Comment: @Holger Sorry if you got offended. No but I do suggest that absolute blanket statements be true. Anyway... "I have never seen anybody doing it." Have you ever seen a WinForms TDI application? If yes, then you've more than likely seen somebody doing it. If you mean drag an `OpenFileDialog` in the designer to a `Panel` on a `Form`, then the result of that action is a function of the designer, irrelavent. At any rate, OFD is not a `Form` or a `Control`. `Controls.Add()` doesn't cause a `Control` to be displayed, and `Form.Show()` is an inherited member from the `Control` class. I hope this helps!

Comment: @rfmodulator You are right, thanks for the update. Just still don't know why one should do it. In what scenario one should favor a Form over a UserControl. The special features of a Form are properties like having a WindowState or a DialogResult and many other features.If you don't want to use any of this, you have picked the wrong class. MDI might be a point,  but the parent necessarily needs to be another form with IsMDIContainer=true, not just a Panel.

Comment: @Holger One should always favor the most appropriate, or most reasonable, for the situation. Scenarios might include 1) you (or someone) also want to use the `Form` stand-alone, 2) you don't own the `Form`. MDI isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you do:

1. Make a custom control, which everything that the form has.
2. Change the form so it only has the custom control.
3. In the panel where you want the form... you put the custom control.

Bonus chatter: you can create a class to represent all the information that the custom control has to show. Then you can pass it around to show it both in the form and in the panel. Oh, and that class is a we call a view model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `frm.content.Controls` is, but this works...

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }

    class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Panel panel1;
        private Button button1;

        public Form1()
        {
            this.panel1 = new Panel();
            this.button1 = new Button();

            this.SuspendLayout();

            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(305, 51);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(457, 338);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;

            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(321, 9);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";

            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();

            form2.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            form2.TopLevel = false;
            form2.AutoScroll = true;

            panel1.Controls.Clear();
            panel1.Controls.Add(form2);

            form2.Show();
        }
    }

    class Form2 : Form
    {
        private Button button1;

        public Form2()
        {
            this.button1 = new Button();

            this.SuspendLayout();

            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(321, 9);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form2";
            this.Text = "Form2";

            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?